# Matplotlib imshow: Data rotated?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to plot some data with scatter. My code is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
data = np.loadtxt('file1.txt')
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
z = data[:,2]
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=100, cmap=mpl.cm.spectral)
cbar=plt.colorbar()
s=18
plt.ylabel(r"$a_v$", size=s)
plt.xlabel(r"$a_{\rm min}$", size=s)
plt.xlim([x.min(),x.max()])
plt.ylim([y.min(),y.max()])
plt.show()
```

The result is
[image]

Now I came on the idea to try imshow with the some data, soince I didn't like the circles of scatter.
So I tried this

```
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.loadtxt('file1.txt')
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
z = data[:,2]

N = 30j
extent = (min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y))

xs,ys = np.mgrid[extent[0]:extent[1]:N, extent[2]:extent[3]:N]

resampled = griddata(x, y, z, xs, ys)

plt.imshow(resampled.T, extent=extent)
s=18
plt.ylabel(r"$a_v$", size=s)
plt.xlabel(r"$a_{\rm min}$", size=s)
plt.xlim([x.min(),x.max()])
plt.ylim([y.min(),y.max()])
cbar=plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

With this result:
[image]

My problem is obviosly why `imshow()` does invert the data? What happens here exactly?

PS: Here are the [data](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8189209/file1.txt), in case someone would like to play with them

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Look at the keyword arguments of `imshow`. There is `origin`. The default is "upper", but you want "lower".

The default makes sense for plotting images, that usually start at the top-left corner. For most matrix-plotting, you'll want `origin="lower"`

Comment: saved my life
 and cost me hours of debugging my "presumably" false function

Answer (score 4):

It's not inverted, just flipped. The origin for `imshow` default to the upper left rather than the lower left. `imshow` has a parameter to specify the origin, it's named origin. Alternatively you can set the default in your `matplotlib.conf`.

Comment: Changing the default globally seems like a bad idea in case you want to run other people's code though.

Answer (score 2):

Consider to use [`pcolormesh`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh) or [`contourf`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf) if you want to plot data of the form `f(X, Y) = Z`. `imshow` simply plots data `Z`, scaling and resampling has do be done manually.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, you could use marker='s' to draw squares in your scatter plot instead of circles and then just keep your original code.

Answer (score 1):

For those who may still have problem with *imshow*, although the `origin` keyword helps, be aware of the coordinate axes as well.

> Generally, for an array of shape (M, N), the first index runs along the vertical, the second index runs along the horizontal. The pixel centers are at integer positions ranging from 0 to N' = N - 1 horizontally and from 0 to M' = M - 1

You can find more details from the [matplotlib website](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html).

For example, consider the following code:

```
M=5; N=10
a=np.zeros((M, N))
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        a[i,j]=i**2
plt.imshow(a, origin="lower")
print(f'here is a:\n{a}\n')
print(f'shape of a: {a.shape}')
print(f'a[0,0]: {a[0,0]}')
print(f'a[0,5]: {a[0,5]}')
print(f'a[0,9]: {a[0,9]}')
print(f'a[4,0]: {a[4,0]}')
```

Here is the output:

[image]