# Matplolib: imgshw() and contourfc() coherent representation?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw 2-d contours of a 2d matrix. I am curious to know if it is normal that imshow() and contour()/contourfc() of matplotlib package work differently with respect the origin of the matrix coordinates. It appears that imshow() treats the origin of coordinates flipped with respect to contour().

I illustrate this with a quite simple example:

```
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    a = np.diag([1.0, 2, 3])
    plt.imshow(a)
```

produces a nice picture with colors along the main diagonal (from left-upper corner to right-bottom corner), But if instead I execute

```
    plt.contour(a)
```

the figure is a set of contours aligned along the perpendicular diagonal (form left-bottom corner to upper-right corner).

If I flip the array with numpy flipud() function

```
    plt.contour(np.flipud(a))
```

then both contour() and imgshw() coincide.

Maybe is a stupid question, I apologize for that !

Thanks anyway

Comment: The default behaviour for images is apparently to plot from top left (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320159/matplotlib-imshow-data-rotated, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823815/matlab-image-and-plot-with-unexpected-flip) while scientific data the origin is typically taken to be the bottom left... This is the same behaviour as matlab.

Comment: Rather than flipping the data, which has led to confusion for me in the past, I now use `origin='lower'`.

Comment: Thanks for both answers !